# Git - how to store different versions of the same file for different clients?

Tags: git

I've got a asp.net web-project and we have different versions of the same default.aspx file for different clients with their logo, text, etc. What is the best way to store this versions in git? If I put one version of default.aspx to a branch named "customer1" for expample, then I'll have to merge my "master" branch to "customer1" every time I commit any changes to master. Is that normal or there is an easy way? May be some auto-merge or smth? Or do I have to write some kind of script to merge them each time my versions are being built on the CI-server?

Comment: I think your code base would diverge doing multi-tenancy this way, via branching. In the past to deal with this, I would have one single default.aspx, but keep all the css/images in a folder per customer. Then based on the url, load the correct css/images into the templates. However, my model was one single code base site (load-balanced) serving multiple customers, I am not sure of your deployment scenario, etc.

Comment: If you can do this by recipe you have makefile targets, not branches.  But how hard is a one-liner to run a gaggle of teeny merges?  Git isn't a deployment server, though it's fairly easy to whip up a poor-man's version based on it.

Comment: @LukeHutton we deploy our site to some folder on our server and then copy it to the remote customer's server. There is different content on the default.aspx for different customers, not only css and images, but also text and layout.

Comment: I see, if the sites are really that different, I would treat them as separate applications and thus, separate repositories.

Comment: @LukeHutton It's only one page, that is different (it is the login page), all other pages are the same.